# How to use sig*set functions in Linux?

Tags: linux, fork, signals, spawn

I am trying to convert a call to spawnp to fork-exec.
But in the code I am working on, they are using the inheritance data structure to pass on some signal settings to the child. These are as follows:

```
memset(&inheritance, 0, sizeof(inheritance));
inheritance.flags = SPAWN_SETSIGDEF;
sigfillset(&inheritance.sigdefault);
inheritance.sigmask = some_default_sig_mask;
spawnp(.......);
```

How do I pass on the signal settings without using spawnp ? Do I use the sigfillset and pthread_procmask functions ? If so, is this syntax correct ? If I just set the sigset variable in sigfillset(), how will the settings get passed on to the process in question ?

```
fork();
if (child process)
 sigemptyset(sigset)
 sigfillset(sigset)
 pthread_procmask(SIG_SETMASK, some_default_sig_mask, NULL);
```

Appreciate your help !

Comment: Note that `inheritance.sigmask` will be ignored unless you also specify SPAWN_SETSIGMASK.

Answer (score 1):

You need to effect two things:  resetting signal disposition on some signals (SPAWN_SETSIGDEF behavior), and setting the new process's mask (SPAWN_SETSIGMASK behavior).

(Note that you don't actually *do* the latter in your example posted, but it is plausible that you intended to.)

### SPAWN_SETSIGDEF

SPAWN_SETSIGDEF resets the disposition of all signals in the `sigdefault` set.  You can effect this by calling [sigaction()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigaction.html) on *each individual signal* you desire to set to default disposition:

```
int spawnlike_setsigdef(const sigset_t *s) { /* FIXME: assert(s != NULL) */
  int signum;
  struct sigaction sa = { 0 };
  sa.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;

  for (signum = 1; signum < NSIG; signum++) { /* You might have to use _NSIG or */
    if (! sigismember(s, signum)) continue;   /* SIGRTMAX or similar.           */

    switch (signum) {
    case SIGKILL:
    case SIGSTOP:     /* Can't modify disposition of these */
      break;
    default:
      if (sigaction(signum, &sa, NULL) == -1)
        return -1; /* Yikes!  What happened? */
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

### SPAWN_SETSIGMASK

SPAWN_SETSIGMASK simply sets the new process's signal mask, which you can do by either [pthread_sigmask()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/sigprocmask.html) or [sigprocmask()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/sigprocmask.html):

**By the way**, you do not specify SPAWN_SETSIGMASK in your spawnp() snippet, so you're not actually explicitly setting the new process's mask.  (It will instead inherit the mask as usual.)

### Putting it together

You'll want something like this:

```
sigset_t all_signals;
sigset_t saved_mask;

sigfillset(&all_signals);

/* Now protect our child as best we can between resetting dispo to SIG_DFL
 * and setting default sig mask.  We'll also reuse 'all_signals' later in
 * the newly fork()d child.
 */
pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &all_signals, &saved_mask);

if (fork() == 0) {
  /* am child */
  spawnlike_setsigdef(all_signals);
  sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &some_default_sig_mask, NULL);
  execv(...);
  fatal_error("execv didn't work :(\n");
}

/* else I am parent, restore my original mask */
pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &all_signals, &saved_mask);
```